# What timer to use to control the API requests?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load test an API and I am trying to make sure I fire only 2 requests in a second due to the throttling limit set at the API Gateway level so if the third request is sent within a second (this happens if the response time of the earlier request is < 1 sec) then I get HTTP-429 error saying 'too many requests'. Please could someone suggest if I can use any timer to achieve this?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) is the easiest of built-in test elements, 2 requests per second is 120 requests per minute. However it is precise enough only on "minute" level so you might need to play with ramp-up period

  [image]
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) is more "precise" but a little bit harder to use as you need to provide controlled throughput and test duration

  [image]
- If you don't mind using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) there is [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) which provides the maximum flexibility and visual way of defining the load

  [image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I already tried constant throughout timer which did not work as I expected. Please could you elaborate - What do you mean by ‘precise enough only on "minute" level so you might need to play with ramp-up period’?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, I suggest the [Arrivals Tread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/). This TG will let you **exactly** configure the desired TPS (Arrival Rate), **plus** the plugin will instantiate the necessary threads to generate the load. No need to guess how many threads/vusers you'll need.

Comment: My requirement is to have only 2 threads. I tried a few timers like Constant Throughput Timer, Precise Throughput Timer, Throughput Shaping Timer but I am still getting HTTP-429 errors even after introducing a ramp-up time of  1min for just 2 users. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.